# Hibernate-Spring boot : spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update recreates tables and columns after update the entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I started Spring Boot project connected to MySQL database. In my `application.properties` I put `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` but still after I update the table name in the entity, a new Table is created, and after I update the column name of property a new column is created.

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/d-gdd?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =


## Hibernate Properties

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: What is your expectation? hibernate will not delete your existing tables

Comment: I don't want hibernate to delete the existing table but just to update them to the new names as if we were doing 
UPDATE TABLE X RENAME TO Y

Answer (score 3):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Please understand that **update** operation will attempt to add new columns, constraints, etc but will **never remove a column or constraint that may have existed previously** but no longer does as part of the object model.

Comment: Yes but if we want to change the table's name what could we do then ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same wondering, however, just like the comment written above,
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` only detects the changes and updates those changes on db as if it's a new thing.

So if you are running locally I suggest do

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`.

But this will delete all the records, so if you really want to "update", then update those column and table names manually.